# Link in Column in CGridView

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I have a 2 problems in my code: 
1) You cannot do a sort by header "Title" when you click on it.
2) You can click on the title, think that will sort alphabetically, an arrow appears, but nothing happens, no sorting.
[image]

**site/index.php**

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => array(
        'title' => array(
            'class'=>'CLinkColumn',
            'labelExpression' => '$data->title',
            'urlExpression'=>'Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."/page/".$data->id',
            'header'=>'Title',
            'headerHtmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:250px;'),
        ),
        'created' => array(
            'name' => 'created',
            'value' => 'date("j.m.Y H:i", $data->created)',
            'headerHtmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:90px;'),
        ),
        'category_id' => array(
            'name' => 'category_id',
            'value' => '$data->category->title',
            'filter' => Category::allCategory(),
            'headerHtmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:150px; text-align:center;'),
        ),
        'subcategory_id' => array(
            'name' => 'subcategory_id',
            'value' => '$data->subcategory->title',
            'filter' => Subcategory::allCategory(),
            'headerHtmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:150px; text-align: center;'),
        ),
        'condition_id' => array(
            'name' => 'condition_id',
            'value'=> '$data->condition->title',
            'filter' => Condition::allAttributes(),
            'headerHtmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:90px;'),
        ),
    ),
));
```

**SiteController**

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Page', array(
            'criteria'=>array(
                'order'=>'id DESC',
            ),
            'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=>30,
            ),
        ));

        // renders the view file 'protected/views/site/index.php'
        // using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'
        $this->render('index', array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider));
    }
```

This controller has not model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your dataProvider with something like this

```
 $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Page', array(
            'criteria'=>array(
                'order'=>'id DESC',
            ),
            'sort' => array(
                'attributes' => array(
                    'title',
                ),
            ),
            'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=>30,
            ),
        ));
```

CLinkColumn does not support sorting, only CDataColumn does 
see [CDataColumn](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataColumn#sortable-detail) and [CLinkColumn](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLinkColumn), you can use Raw type to make sortable Links instead as below

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
     'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
     'enableSorting'=>true,
     'columns' => array(
            'title' => array(
                   'name'=>'title',
                   'headerHtmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:250px;'),
                   'type'=>'raw',
                   'value'=>'CHtml::link($data->title,Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."/page/".$data->id)'
            ),
```

Comment: Manquer, nothing happens!

Comment: 'sort' => array(
                'attributes' => array(
                    'title',
                    'created',
                    'category_id',
                    'subcategory_id',
                    'condition_id',
                ),

Comment: The header "title" does not appear as a link instead of just text. And must be a link.

Comment: you also may need to enable sorting for the column itself

Comment: I did it the same result, but nothing happened.

Comment: my apologies only CDataColumn has sortable property see :http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataColumn#sortable-detail and not CLinkColumn

Comment: Maybe it's because there is no model, and the data that the model is taken from Page CGridview?

Comment: OK, but why then does not work the other columns? They are not CLinkColumn.

Comment: try 'sortable'=>true in the title array .

Comment: @AlexMalev you have to make 'sortable'=>true for other column arrays and use Raw column type for title as I have mentioned in the modified answer

Comment: Thank you! Links appear as Headers + links, but sorting still does not work.

Comment: can you tell me what happens when you click on the link in the header ( i.e. the URL being queried ? )

Comment: domain.com/site/index?Page_sort=title&ajax=yw0 if I click on "Title" and the data in the column are not changed.

Comment: that seems correct. not sure whats going wrong.. try checking the sql logs and see if there is problem with the query

Comment: Decision. $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Page', array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
            'sort' => array(
                'defaultOrder'=>array(
                    'id'=>"DESC"
                )),
            'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=>30,
            ),
        ));

Comment: defaultOrder will return a sorted list on initial load per the logic you configured, it will not fix the sorting problem you are facing..